# Accessing JMenuItems from JMenuBarbar in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, menuitem, jmenu, jmenubar

I'm working with some java code specifically on a menu bar right now and I'm having trouble accessing a menu item from a JMenuBar. The menu bar has an item JMenu, and the JMenu has a JMenuItem in it, I'm trying to access the JMenuItem, differentiating items by the name attribute (this is just one way I found to differentiate between them, if anybody knows a better way to do this please let me know.) I'm doing this on the on-change event in switching tabs in my application, so here is my code.

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++){
            MenuElement[] subItems = menuItems[i].getSubElements();
            for(int j = 0; j < subItems.length; j++){
                    System.out.println(subItems[j].getComponent().getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The menuItems comes from a getSubElements() call on the JMenuBar, I can get the 'File' element, but when I do the second loop to find the item underneath 'File' most of the attributes including name are null, even though I set name already.

In the debugger I can see the name I set when doing a watch on subItems[j].getComponent(), under a section labeled 'component', then under 'element data[0]'.

I'm sure there's a way to get to this attribute but I haven't been able to figure out how. Does anybody know how to access this or know a better way to distinguish between MenuItems from a JMenuBar?

Thanks.

EDIT - I figured it out. If anybody is curious the JMenuItem was nested within another layer in the JMenu. This code prints out the name I was trying to find.

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
    if(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() != 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++){
            MenuElement[] subItems = menuItems[i].getSubElements();
            for(int j = 0; j < subItems.length; j++){
                MenuElement[] subSubItems = subItems[j].getSubElements();
                for(int k = 0; k < subSubItems.length; k++){
                    System.out.println(subSubItems[k].getComponent().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That being said I have no idea why this is. Anybody know?
Here is the code that builds the JMenuBar:

```
public void buildMenu(){
    menuBar = frame.getJMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("File");
    menu.setName("file");
    menuBar.add(menu);
    importTiles = buildImportTilesMenuItem();
    menu.add(importTiles);
}

public JMenuItem buildImportTilesMenuItem(){
    importTiles = new JMenuItem("Import Tiles");
    importTiles.setName("importTiles");
    importTiles.addActionListener(this);
    return importTiles;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you have to do drill down again is that each JMenu child items are created in a JpopupMenu Container. So the File Menu has got the JPopupMenu container which has got your importTiles JMenuItem.
So the code can be changed like this:

```
MenuElement[] topLevelElements = frameApp.getJMenuBar().getSubElements();
            //Get top level elements--> FileMenu etc
            for(MenuElement menuElement: topLevelElements)
            {
                MenuElement[] subElements = menuElement.getSubElements();
                //get the child elements which are of type JPopupMenu
                for(MenuElement subElement:subElements)
                {
                     //This is the popuMenu which contains child elements
                    System.out.println(subElement.toString());
                    if(subElement instanceof JPopupMenu)
                    {
                        //show child elements
                        for(MenuElement childMenuItem:subElement.getSubElements())
                        {
                            //New and Save here ...
                            System.out.println("ChildMenu Name=>" + childMenuItem.getComponent().getName());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //display names directly
                    }
                }
            }
```